# SSL for selected controller and selected function name [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am here with a serious issue of my site. I am not a php developer but I know the basics. So if I make any mistake here, please try to forgive me.

My site is built with CodeIgnitor and I have SSL for some selected pages which is controlled by controller or controller name or function name.

Like - I am having SSL for these

```
$ssl_controllers = array('controller1','controller2','controller3');
```

URL structure is like this - `https://mysite.com/controller1`

Now, I have several functions inside each controller. Like this - inside of "controller1", I have "function_1()"

So the url for will be - `https://mysite/controller1/function_1`

Now I dont need SSL for "funtion_1" which is written inside of "controller1"

If I need to remove the SSL for "function_1", I need to remove whole "controller1" from the array. But I don't need that as there is other functions that require SSL.

So how I can remove SSL for "function_1"?

Is there a way to remove a function name from the array?

like this - $ssl_controllers =

```
$ssl_controllers = array('controller1'==>'function_1','controller2','controller3');
```

Please help me!!

Thanks!

---

As I am not using htaccess for redirection, your method is not working in my case. If I use htaccess, it gives me endless loop that cannot be completed!! This is because I am using CodeIgnitor library for redirection and specific page SSL

---

Here is the PHP code -

```
class CI_ssl{

    function check_ssl()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
        $ssl_controllers = array('controller1','controller2','controller3');

        if(in_array($class,$ssl_controllers))
        {                       
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);          

            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) 
                redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
        else
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) 
                redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }
```

This gives me SSL for specific pages and redirects other to only http://

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after a research today, I finally have resolved my issue. Here is the demo -

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
$ssl_controllers = array('controller1','controller2','controller3');
```

In this code, I have called the specific function this way -

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
$ssl_controllers = array('controller1','controller2','controller3');
$my_function = $CI->router->fetch_method(); // fetch method is used for getting the specific function name
$ssl_functions = array('function_1'); // specific function name in array
```

Then, I just added elseif statement to my condition -

```
if(in_array($my_function,$ssl_functions))
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) 
                redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
        elseif(in_array($class,$ssl_controllers))
        {                       
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);          
            //echo $CI->config->config['base_url']."=>".$CI->uri->uri_string()."=>".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];exit;           
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) 
                redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
        else
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) 
                redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }
```

Thus my new url comes without SSL! like this -

```
http://mysite/controller1/function_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rewrite rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} controller1/function_1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/controller1/function_1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: Your base_url must be set to "/" in your config file.

Comment: Hello sir, as I am not using htaccess for redirection, your method is not working in my case. If I use htaccess, it gives me endless loop that cannot be completed!!

This is because I am using CodeIgnitor library for redirection and specific page SSL.